# drupal_http_get_header() not returning headers

Tags: apache, drupal, drupal-7, header

Using Drupal 7-x, I'm trying to retrieve a custom header (in my local it was added via httpd.conf), and on production servers added by varnish (X-Country-Code).

when outputting drupal_http_get_header(), all I get in the returned array is x-ip-whitelist as an array value (nothing else; no status, connection, x-generator, nada).

Any ideas? Wondering if my custom module is being fired too soon before the response is created, which might explain (in my limited understanding) as to why there are no headers available?

If the call to drupal_http_get_header() is firing 'too early' to pick up headers, is there a way to rank my module so it gets called later? This might screw up other stuff my module is using however.

Comment: Can you add your varnish config and the apache part?

Comment: Unfortunately the Varnish/Apache part is out of my hands (handled by another company); we're the Drupal engine below all that.

I did, however, find a workaround for now using $_SERVER['HTTP_X_COUNTRY_CODE'] as a fallback. That oddly was part of the call.

Comment: I saw the same thing. Was sending a curl request against an NGINX server (and then after to a drupal instance) and didn't see any headers set, but `$_SERVER['HTTP_HEADERNAME']` was set.